# SELinux fcontext after svn checkout

Tags: svn, selinux

I'd like to start by telling that there's no real problem and everything works as I would expect, however I am experiencing an odd behaviour which I cannot explain, so looking for some insight from more skilled engineers.

The odd behaviour is observed with how SELinux applies fcontext mapping definitions.

Let me start by printing SELinux fcontext policies which applies to my case:

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-40 wp-content]# semanage fcontext -l | grep "^/var/www.*httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0\s$"
/var/www/svn(/.*)?                                 all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0
/var/www/html(/.*)?/uploads(/.*)?                  all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0
/var/www/html(/.*)?/wp-content(/.*)?               all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0
/var/www/html(/.*)?/sites/default/files(/.*)?      all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0
/var/www/html(/.*)?/sites/default/settings\.php    regular file       system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0
/var/www/moodledata(/.*)?                          all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0
/var/www/moodle/data(/.*)?                         all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0
/var/www/gallery/albums(/.*)?                      all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0
/var/www/html/owncloud/data(/.*)?                  all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0
/var/www/html/configuration\.php                   all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0
```

As you can see from the command, I am interested in fcontext policies enabling httpd to write inside **/var/www**.

I’m setting up a WordPress installation, so my eyes lock on these policies:

```
/var/www/html(/.*)?/uploads(/.*)?                  all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0
/var/www/html(/.*)?/wp-content(/.*)?               all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0
```

From the policy RegExp I can desifer what directory structure I need to have. Let’s create a directory for the project and checkout.

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-40 /]# mkdir -p /var/www/html/sun
[root@ip-10-0-0-40 /]# cd /var/www/html/sun
[root@ip-10-0-0-40 sun]# svn co http://server/ .
```

Let’s check if we have right fcontext applied:

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-40 sun]# cd /var/www/html/sun/public/wp-content
[root@ip-10-0-0-40 wp-content]# ls -Z
-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 index.php
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 languages
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 mu-plugins
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 plugins
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 themes
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 uploads
```

Great! Just for an interest and double-check, let's try to restore fcontext and see what happens:

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-40 wp-content]# restorecon -Rv /var/www/html/sun/
[root@ip-10-0-0-40 wp-content]# ls -Z
-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 index.php
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 languages
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 mu-plugins
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 plugins
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 themes
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 uploads
```

Great! Works as expected.

To finish the test, let’s simulate an expected failure. Let’s create a project directory outside of **/html/**, like here: **/var/www/sun** and checkout.

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-40 wp-content]# mkdir -p /var/www/sun
[root@ip-10-0-0-40 wp-content]# cd /var/www/sun/
[root@ip-10-0-0-40 sun]# svn co http://server/ .
```

Let’s check if we have right fcontext applied:

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-40 sun]# cd /var/www/sun/public/wp-content/
[root@ip-10-0-0-40 wp-content]# ls –Z
-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 index.php
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 languages
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 mu-plugins
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 plugins
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 themes
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 uploads
```

Odd, I was expecting to see **httpd_sys_content_t** (default fcontext), let’s try to restore to default:

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-40 wp-content]# restorecon -Rv /var/www/sun
...Output omitted
[root@ip-10-0-0-40 wp-content]# ls -Z
-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 index.php
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 languages
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 mu-plugins
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 plugins
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 themes
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 uploads
```

Using **restorecon** for **/var/www/sun** works as expected, however… the puzzle is:

**Why svn co inside /var/www/sun have used non existing policies? The policy match fcontext but not the location for this:**

```
/var/www/html(/.*)?/wp-content(/.*)?               all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0
```

As well **index.php** have differect **fcontext**, but directories have the same: **httpd_sys_rw_content_t**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same question, "Why are *wp-content* directories automatically labelled with **httpd_sys_rw_content_t** even outside of the fcontext rules for */var/www/html* ?". However, I've now found the answer and thought I'd post it here.

It's caused by a feature of SELinux called Filename Transitions which are a policy mechanism to help create correctly labelled files and directories.

In your example, the directory */var/www/sun/public* inherits **httpd_sys_content_t** down from */var/www*.

Ordinarily, a directory called *wp-content* that is created inside a */var/www/sun/public* would also inherit **httpd_sys_content_t**.

But in *apache.if* there's a file name transition rule which says that any directory called "wp-content" that would have been created with **httpd_sys_content_t** should instead be created as **httpd_sys_rw_content_t**

In CentOS 7, install *selinux-policy-devel* package and you can see the definition in */usr/share/selinux/devel/include/contrib/apache.if*

```
filetrans_pattern($1, httpd_sys_content_t, httpd_sys_rw_content_t, dir, "wp-content")
```

You can test the theory as follows:

```
[root@dt-laptop-centos7 /]# mkdir junk
[root@dt-laptop-centos7 /]# ls -aldZ junk
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0 junk
[root@dt-laptop-centos7 /]# chcon -t httpd_sys_content_t junk
[root@dt-laptop-centos7 /]# ls -aldZ junk
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 junk
[root@dt-laptop-centos7 /]# cd junk
[root@dt-laptop-centos7 junk]# mkdir wp-otherdir
[root@dt-laptop-centos7 junk]# mkdir wp-content
[root@dt-laptop-centos7 junk]# ls -alZ
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 .
dr-xr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:root_t:s0      ..
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 wp-content
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 wp-otherdir
```

You can see that *wp-content* has it's context automatically set to **httpd_sys_rw_content_t** whereas *wp-otherdir* just inherits **httpd_sys_content_t**